# How do I import an obj with hair and have the hair look like hair?

Tags: import, hair

I am trying to import an obj into blender and the hair looks more like sheets of paper then hair. How do I fix it into a model with hair that is more like a mesh (not reliant on a picture to add texture/definition)? I don't need it to have color or anything, just look like model hair, not paper sheets.

I am taking blender classes, but still a noob. Please use small words when answering :)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Those are generally called polygon hairs and rely on an image texture to get the correct look of hair. Without the texture they are mostly useless, but they work universally and are lightweight. In Blender you can use a Hair based particle system to replace the geometry based one, but it is a Blender specific simulation, and you can't for the most part export particle based hair to other applications.

Comment: To be clear you can't "*import an obj with hair*", the hair is already there,
 all you can do is erase the hair that comes with it, then replace it in Blender with a particle system. Check the [Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/particles/hair/index.html) about hair particles.